# htaccess old php pages to new wordpress ones

Tags: htaccess

I'm redesigning a site and converting to wordpress. I want to redirect the old pages to the new ones.

Also, wordpress is installed in a directory, but viewable as if it was in the root.

So the following htaccess actually works, but I want to change the top line so that it catches all the pages in the root and redirects them to the proper place

```
# CHANGE THIS LINE TO CATCH ALL PAGES
Redirect 302 /PAGENAME.php http://www.example.com/PAGENAME

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitefiles/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your line with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: tried, it didn't do anything

Comment: Hmm well that takes any domain/$.php to domain/$ Is this an apache host?

Comment: sorry, I thought I replied to this but I guess it didn't go through.  Yes, it is apache

Comment: Ok since my brain isn't working this morning, have you tried the redirection plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/